# Can I read my google apps account mail using powershell/c#

Tags: email, gmail, imap

I used to have this working with Koolwired years ago but it appears this project has gone stale and google have changed their settings. I have no problem  sending mail to my apps account of course but reading the mailbox is another matter. Looking for either a .Net/powershell solution.

I've been using imap.gmail.com as the server

Cheers